# Selenium C# Error while reading data from Excel for data driven testing

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, c#-4.0, data-driven-tests

I am trying to perform Data driven testing by loading client codes from Excel file to login and perform other operation.I am trying to iterate my test for all clients in the client_code column. I only need to read client_code column and get data to repeat same test with those clients. I am getting Null value when I run below code

Any help with this would be much appreciated thank you.

I am using ExcelDataReader v3.4.0, ExcelDataReader.DataSet v3.4.0, selenium Webdriver v3.11.0

My Excel table looks like below.

```html
client_code  client_name
11111   Client1
22222   Client2
33333   Client3
44444   Client4
55555   Client5
```

This is my code:

ExcelUtil.cs

```html
using ExcelDataReader;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace MyDemoAutomation
    {
    public class ExcelUtil
        {
        public DataTable ExcelToDatable(string fileName)
            {
            // open file and returns as stream
            FileStream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            // create openXmlReader via ExcelReaderFactory
            IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
            //Set the first row as column name
          var result1 = excelReader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
                {
                ConfigureDataTable = (_) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
                    {
                    UseHeaderRow = true
                    }
                });
     
            // Return as dataset
            DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
            // Get all tables
            DataTableCollection table = result.Tables;
            // Store in Database
            DataTable resultTable = table["Sheet1"];
            // return
            return resultTable;

            }

        List<DataCollection> dataCol = new List<DataCollection>();
        public void PopulateInCollection(string fileName)
            {

            DataTable table = ExcelToDatable(fileName);
            for (int row = 1; row <= table.Rows.Count; row++)
                {

                for (int col = 0; col < table.Columns.Count; col++)
                    {

                    DataCollection dtTable = new DataCollection()
                        {

                        rowNumber = row,
                        colName = table.Columns[col].ColumnName,
                        colValue = table.Rows[row - 1][col].ToString()
                        };
                    dataCol.Add(dtTable);

                    }
                }
            }

        public string ReadData(int rowNumber, string columnName)
            {
            try
                {
                // Retriving data using LINQ to reduce much of iterations
                string data = (from colData in dataCol
                               where colData.colName == columnName && colData.rowNumber == rowNumber
                               select colData.colValue).SingleOrDefault();

                return data.ToString();
                }
            catch (Exception e)
                {
                return null;
                }
            }

        internal class DataCollection
            {
            public int rowNumber { get; internal set; }
            public string colName { get; internal set; }
            public string colValue { get; internal set; }
            }
        }
    }
```

Test Class :

```html
 [Test]
        public void DataDrivenTest_FromExcel()
            {

   Driver = new ChromeDriver();
   
            ExcelUtil util = new ExcelUtil();
            util.PopulateInCollection(@"C:\dan\AutomationTest\TestData\test.xlsx");

   Driver.FindElement(By.Id("contentPlaceholder_txtClientCode")).SendKeys(util.ReadData(i));
   
   Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='btnLogin']")).Click();
   Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='tabContent0']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]")).Click();
   Driver.FindElement(By.Id("contentPlaceholder_txtcloseButton")).Click();
   
   Driver.Quit

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @Miguel D'Alessio I tried running the code you provided. Below is the exact copy paste code which I am running with error. Thank you.

ExcelReader Class:

```html
namespace Automation
    {
    class ExcelReader
        {
        public List<TestCaseData> ReadExcelData(string excelFile, string sheetname)
            {
            string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetname + "$]";

            if (!File.Exists(excelFile))
                throw new Exception(string.Format("File name: {0}", excelFile), new
            FileNotFoundException());

            string connectionStr =
             string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\";", excelFile);
            var ret = new List<TestCaseData>();
            using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionStr))
                {
                connection.Open();
                var command = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, connection);
                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader == null)
                    throw new Exception(string.Format("No data return from file, file name:{ 0 }", excelFile));
                while (reader.Read())
                    {
                    var row = new List<string>();
                    var feildCnt = reader.FieldCount;
                    for (var i = 0; i < feildCnt; i++)
                        row.Add(reader.GetValue(i).ToString());
                    ret.Add(new TestCaseData(row.ToArray()));
                    }
                }
            return ret;
            }
        }
    }
```

Test Class :

```html
namespace Automation
    {
    [TestFixture]
    class Excel_TC_1 
        {
        private readonly string testCaseData;

        public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> BudgetData
            {
            get
                {
                List<TestCaseData> testCaseDataList = new ExcelReader().ReadExcelData(@"C:\Safety_dan\AutomationTest\TestData\test.xlsx",
                    "Sheet1");
                if (testCaseDataList != null)
                    foreach (TestCaseData testCaseData in testCaseDataList)
                        yield return testCaseData;
                }
            }


        [Test]
        [TestCaseSource(typeof(Excel_TC_1), "BudgetData")]
        public void TestCase1(string attribbutte1)
            {
            // Login

            CcLoginPageObject ccPageLogin = new CcLoginPageObject();
            ClientLoginPageObject clientLoginPage = new ClientLoginPageObject();

                ccPageLogin.Login("username", "password");
          
            // Loading client code:
            Driver.FindElement(By.Id("ClientsSearch")).SendKeys(testCaseData);

            }
        }
        }
```

Error:

```html
Test Name: TestCase1
Test FullName: Automation.Excel_TC_1.TestCase1
Test Source: C:\Safety_dan\-localRepoVisualStudioC#\Automation\Excel_TC_1.cs : line 32
Test Outcome: Failed
Test Duration: 0:00:00.005

Result StackTrace: 
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbServicesWrapper.GetDataSource(OleDbConnectionString constr, DataSourceWrapper& datasrcWrapper)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
   at Automation.ExcelReader.ReadExcelData(String excelFile, String sheetname) in C:\Safety_dan\-localRepoVisualStudioC#\Automation\Excel_TC_1.cs:line 27
   at Automation.Excel_TC_1.<get_BudgetData>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\Safety_dan\-localRepoVisualStudioC#\Automation\Excel_TC_1.cs:line 20
   at NUnit.Framework.TestCaseSourceAttribute.GetTestCasesFor(IMethodInfo method) in C:\src\nunit\nunit\src\NUnitFramework\framework\Attributes\TestCaseSourceAttribute.cs:line 177
Result Message: System.InvalidOperationException : The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can:

**READ EXCEL FILE:**

```
class ExcelReader
 {
 public List<TestCaseData> ReadExcelData(string excelFile, string sheetname)
 {
    string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetname+ "$]";

    if (!File.Exists(excelFile))
        throw new Exception(string.Format("File name: {0}", excelFile), new 
    FileNotFoundException());

    string connectionStr = 
     string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\";", excelFile);
    var ret = new List<TestCaseData>();
    using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionStr))
    {
        connection.Open();
        var command = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, connection);
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader == null)
            throw new Exception(string.Format("No data return from file, 
        file name:{0}", excelFile));
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var row = new List<string>();
            var feildCnt = reader.FieldCount;
            for (var i = 0; i < feildCnt; i++)
                row.Add(reader.GetValue(i).ToString());
            ret.Add(new TestCaseData(row.ToArray()));
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Your test case will remain like this:

```
      [TestFixture]
class TC_1
{

  public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> BudgetData
    {
        get
        {
            List<TestCaseData> testCaseDataList = new ExcelReader().ReadExcelData(//path//document.xlsx",
                "SheetName");
            if (testCaseDataList != null)
                foreach (TestCaseData testCaseData in testCaseDataList)
                    yield return testCaseData;
        }
    }


    [Test]     
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(TC_1), "BudgetData")]
    public void TestCase1(string attribbutte1, string .....)
    {
     ........................................
```

NOTE: You need to install the reference "Acces Database Engine" to Read Excel Files

NOTE2: by default the first row will be of titles, for each new row the TC will be executed

[image]

the same code is executed 5 times changing the data

Comment: Thank you Miguel D'Alessio. Its a dumb question but Could you please tell me how to reference "Acces Database Engine", from Manage NuGet Packages or from Reference > Add reference. I tried looking but could not find that. Thank you in advance.

Comment: when copying and pasting the code, when you compile and run it will give you an error (not in all cases) you may need Access Database, you must download it and install it outside of Visual Studio

Comment: Hi @Miguel D'Alessio, thank you for clarification. I have included error message above now.I am new to c# and on my laptop i don't have admin access to install Access Database. I already have Microsoft SQL Server 2017 installed. Is there any way i can read data without installing Access Database or by using Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Did you try running the test?

Comment: hi @ Miguel D'Alessio  I tried running the code provided by you. I have added exact code test class and error above. Thank you